# Magento 2.1: How to handle custom payment grand total mismatch upon return to the merchant ?site

Tags: magento2, orders, payment-methods, payment-gateway, magento-2.1.1

The customer payment gateway I'm working on is based on the workflow of PayPal Express checkout. Upon the checkout, the user will be redirected to the payment site and then return back to the Magento store after the payment is completed.

Here's the catch, PayPal Express keep the shopping cart as quote until the user is returned and then convert quote into order. If the user were to modify the shopping cart on a different browser tab and continued with the PayPal payment. The final charge amount will still reflect the latest shopping cart grand total.

Unfortunately, my custom payment gateway has the transaction occurred on their site before returning back to the merchant. So if the user were to modify the shopping cart on separate tab, the grand total would be mismatched with the paid amount.

We consider to add the validation that will fail the order creation if the payment doesn't match with the final grand total. However, the payment will be made to the merchant, but no order will be created on the store.

If we were to create an order first before sending to the payment gateway, if the user were to cancel the payment, then the order will be canceled as well. However, we may end up having the situation where someone is messing with the system and end up throwing a large numbers of cancelled orders on the system.

Since the payment amount cannot be altered while the user is on the payment gateway site, what would be the best way to handle this situation?

Thank you,